# Transitioning view controllers

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I keep seeing how to do this with iOS or some other suggestions but none of them are working for me. The one that seemed promising didn't work either! What I am trying to do is have the user login to the software. Once they login it will move on to a different view controller and hide the login view controller. If there is a better way of doing this I would love to hear it, because I am still learning all of this. What I have done is in Xcode, I created a new view controller called MainViewController, and I have the other view controller that is loginViewController and is the startup controller. In the visual studio I created a view controller file which gave me MainView and MainViewController.cs. I added a button to my login view controller and then in the button event I added this code:

```
partial voide btnLogin(NSObject sender)
{
     this.View.Superview.AddSubView(new MainViewController().View);
     this.View.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
```

When I run this all it does is make the button disappear and doesn't move over to the other view controller and hide itself. When I add a segue it will move to the other view controller but leave the login controller open.

I am so lost on this and I am hoping someone can guide me in the right direction!

Thanks for any assistance you can give!

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT It did not fix the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is have the user login to the software. Once
> they login it will move on to a different view controller and hide the
> login view controller.

You can switch between different view controller by change the rootViewControlle:

```
public void BtnLogin(NSObject sender)
{

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController = new MainViewController();

}
```

In Xamarin.Mac, it should be something like this:

```
public void BtnLogin(NSObject sender)
{
        MainViewController vc = new MainViewController();
        vc.View.Window.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
        NSApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.ContentViewController = vc;
}
```

Comment: So when I put that in the button, when I click the button it disappears and still doesn't show the view controller. The other view controller I have a button that has 'main' in its text but I get a black screen. Am I doing something wrong!?

Comment: `I have a button that has 'main' in its text`, are you sure you have added this button to the MainViewController? See my updated answer to check if you get a MainViewController with blue background.

Comment: I think I am screwing this up some how. When I try to do the code you have above it will not allow me to type vc.View.Background.

So maybe I am not adding the view controller correctly. I got into Xamarin and I add a new ViewController under the Mac section and name It MainView. I then go into Xcode and I add a view controller to the project in there. What am I missing here? There is not a lot of guides online for Xamarin.Mac unfortunately so I having a difficult time with this!

Comment: Have a try with `vc.View.Window.BackgroundColor`.